# Using gdal (1.11.0) to export from SQL Server 2008 R2 to KML

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, gdal, ogr

I've got a SQL Server table that I'd like to turn into a KML file. I've kind of got it working, but not quite. Here's my command:

```
C:\Temp\gdal>ogr2ogr -f "KML" "test.kml" "MSSQL:server=devbox;database=test;trusted_conneciton=yes" -sql "SELECT name, street, city, state, zip, latitude, longitude, geog FROM dbo.addrlist" -dsco NameField=name -dsco DescriptionField=desc -overwrite
```

I get a valid kml file, but it's missing the POINT. Here is how all of the `<Placemark>` tags look:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Test Subject</name>
  <description>Wilmington</description>
  <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#SELECT">
    <SimpleData name="street">120 Main</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="city">Wilmington</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="state">DE</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="zip">19802</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="latitude">39.70004</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="longitude">-76.214</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="geog">C1FF56B20D53C028F224E99AD94340</SimpleData>
  </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```

I should have something like this in there:

```
<Point id="1">
  <extrude>0</extrude>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
  <coordinates>-76.214, 39.70004, 0</coordinates>
</Point>
```

When I look at the KML in Google Earth, there are no points to display.

The "geog" column is of geography datatype (SRID: 4269).

I've tried using `-f LIBKML` as well, but get the same basic problem (no point). I see there are a lot of additional options with this driver, but I don't know how to adjust the call to `ogr2ogr`.

Once it is working, I'd like to call this from a scheduled Powershell script.

Thoughts?

Comment: you might have to reproject to 4326 first, or replace the geog with geog.STAsBinary() in your query. see here for an example: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/